# Labor percentage and wages from clock in/out and sales records

Tags: php, datetime, database

I'm developing a PHP function for calculating labor percentage (labor cost/sales) accounting for daily and weekly overtime rules, if applicable, based on the payroll period; the wages for each employee in the time input search range are calculated then summed to determine total labor cost.

The function takes start/end date/times from datetime pickers as POST data for the search range of sales and shift records, but can be hardcoded in as UTC stamps.

Intended for use with a DB containing tables for sales records (UNIX timestamp,amount) and employee clock in/out records (`StaffID`, `ClockIn`, `ClockOut`, `RegRate`, `OvertimeRate`) but similarly structured arrays will work just fine.

I'm looking for any criticisms or suggestions, tried to use verbose variable names for clarity.

Updated: I added the logic for calculating the employees' earnings for each shift, using the same payroll/overtime considerations. Response now returns (`StaffID`,`TotalEarnings`,`TotalTime`) records as well as the original clock in/out records in the search range with the `ShiftEarnings` appended.

```
<?php    
function labor_summary_post() {
  $ONEWEEKSECONDS = 604800;
  $ONEDAYSECONDS = 86400;

  $weeklimit = 0;   //weekly overtime hours threshold; 0 = no weekly OT  consideration e.g. 40
  $daylimit = 0;    //daily overtime hours threshold; 0 = no daily OT consideration e.g. 8
  $payrollstart = 0; //day of the week payroll starts; Sun-Sat = 0-6

  $offset = 0;  //time offset from UTC default in seconds

  $startDate = strtotime($this->post('startDate')); //unix timestamp of query start date
  $endDate = strtotime($this->post('endDate')); //unix timestamp of query end date

  if ($this->post('startTime')){    //optional
    $startTime = strtotime($this->post('startTime')); //unix timestamp of query start time
    $startminute = date('i', $startTime);   //0-59
    $starthour = date('H', $startTime); //0-23
    $startseconds = date('s', $startTime); // 1-12
  }
  else{ //defaults to 00:00
    $startTime = 0;
    $startminute = 0;
    $starthour = 0;
    $startseconds = 0;
 }
 if($this->post('endTime')){    //end time provided
     $endTime = strtotime($this->post('endTime')); //unix timestamp of query end time
    $endminute = date('i', $endTime);
    $endhour = date('H', $endTime);
    $endseconds = date('s', $endTime);
  }else{    //defaults to 00:00
    $endTime = 0;
    $endminute = 0;
    $endhour = 0;
    $endseconds = 0;
  }

  $start = $startDate + ($starthour *3600) + ($startminute *60) +      $startseconds; //query start in seconds
  $end = $endDate + ($endhour *3600) + ($endminute *60) + $endseconds;  //query end in seconds
  if($endTime == 0){  //only end date provided; assume end of day
    $end += $ONEDAYSECONDS;
  }

  $startz = $start - $offset; //start, timezone adjusted
  $endz = $end - $offset; //end, timezone adjusted

  //day of nearest, prior payroll start 
  $startweekday = date('w', $startDate);
  if($startweekday < $payrollstart){
    $daystoprevpayroll = 7 - ($payrollstart - $startweekday);
  } else{
    $daystoprevpayroll = abs($payrollstart - $startweekday);
  }
  $timetoprevpayroll = $daystoprevpayroll * $ONEDAYSECONDS;
  $bufferedstarttime = ($startDate - $timetoprevpayroll) - $offset; //most recent payroll start

  $query = //multiarray of clock in/out staff records: Where bufferedstartime<=ClockIn<=endz
        //should exclude records where ClockOut == null
  $staffquery = //multiarray of staff (StaffID) who worked during range

  $employees = array(); //multiarray of shifts by employee
  $numShifts = count($query[0]);  //count of shift records
  //iterate through shifts
  for($i = 0; $i < $numShifts; $i++){
    $shift = $query[0][$i];
    $staffID = $shift['StaffID']; //employee identifier

    //arrange shifts by employee
    if(!array_key_exists($staffID, $employees)) {
      $employees[$staffID] = array();
    }
    array_push($employees[$staffID], $shift);
  }

  $newstaff = array(); //for returning cropped shift results
  $shiftrecords = array(); //for returning shift records w/ earnings added

  $totalRegHours = 0;   //sum of all regular hours worked by all employees
  $totalRegDollars = 0; //sum of all regular dollars earned by all employees
  $totalOverHours = 0;  //sum of all overtime hours worked by all employees
  $totalOverDollars = 0;    //sum of all overtime dollars earned by all employees

  //iterate through each employee
  foreach ($employees as $employee){
    $weekindex = 1; //current week in the iteration
    $dailyhourtotal = 0;    //sum of hours worked in current day
    $weeklyhourtotal = 0;   //sum of hours worked in current week
    $prevday = -1;  //tracks day of current shift
    $totalEarnings = 0; //record earnings of employee's shifts within provided date range
    $totalTime = 0; //record time of shifts within provided date range

    //iterate through each shift of the current employee
    foreach($employee as $shift){
      $currentday = date('d', ($shift['ClockIn'])); //index of the shift's day
      $clockin = $shift['ClockIn']; //stamp of shift start
      $clockout = $shift['ClockOut']; //stamp of shift end
      $duration = $clockout - $clockin; //length of shift
      $shiftearnings = 0.0; //earnings for given shift
      $staffID = $shift['StaffID'];

      $regRate = $shift['RegRate']; //employee's regular pay rate for the shift
      $overRate = $shift['OverRate'];   //employees OT rate for the shift

      $include = false; //include shift in labor % calculation

      //new week, if considered
      if($weeklimit > 0 && $clockin > ($bufferedstarttime + ($ONEWEEKSECONDS * $weekindex))){
        $weeklyhourtotal = 0;
        $weekindex += 1;
      }

      //new day, if considered
      if($daylimit > 0 && $currentday != $prevday){
        $dailyhourtotal = 0;
      }

      //punches don't fall in search range, but employee was punched in
      if($clockin <= $startz && $clockout >= $endz){
        $duration = $duration - ($startz - $clockin)/3600 - ($clockout - $endz)/3600;
        $include = true;
      }
      //shift exceeds end date, truncate length
      else if($clockin >= $startz && $clockin <= $endz && $clockout >= $endz){
        $duration = $duration - ($clockout - $endz)/3600;
        $include = true;
      }
      //shift starts before search and enters range
      else if($clockin <= $startz && $clockout >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz){
        $duration = $duration - ($startz - $clockin)/3600;
        $include = true;
      }

      /* Calculate hours and pay
        Shifts in the buffered payroll range but outside the search range are excluded
        Each case applies the check before adding shift data to totals
      */

      //CASE 1: Both daily and weekly will exceed overtime
      if($weeklimit > 0 && $daylimit > 0
        && $dailyhourtotal <= $daylimit && $dailyhourtotal + $duration > $daylimit
        && $weeklyhourtotal <= $weeklimit && $weeklyhourtotal + $duration > $weeklimit){
        $dailydif = ($duration + $dailyhourtotal) - $daylimit;  //day amount that exceeds OT limit
        $weeklydif = ($duration + $weeklyhourtotal) - $weeklimit; //week amount that exceeds OT
        if($dailydif >= $weeklydif  //day hours remainder is greater
            && (($clockin >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz) || $include)){
          $totalRegHours += ($daylimit - $dailyhourtotal);
          $totalRegDollars += ($daylimit - $dailyhourtotal) * $regRate;
          $totalOverHours += $dailydif;
          $totalOverDollars += $dailydif * $overRate;
          $shiftearnings += ($daylimit - $dailyhourtotal) * $regRate;
          $shiftearnings += $dailydif * $overRate;
        }
        else if($weeklydif > $dailydif
            && (($clockin >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz) || $include)){
          $totalRegHours += $weeklimit - $weeklyhourtotal;
          $totalRegDollars += ($weeklimit - $weeklyhourtotal) * $regRate;
          $totalOverHours += $weeklydif;
          $totalOverDollars += $weeklydif * $overRate;
          $shiftearnings += ($weeklimit - $weeklytotalhours) * $regRate;
          $shiftearnings += $weeklydif * $overRate;
        }
      }
      //CASE 2: Already in weekly overtime
      else if($weeklimit > 0 && $weeklyhourtotal > $weeklimit
          && (($clockin >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz) || $include)){
        $totalOverHours += $duration;
        $totalOverDollars += $duration * $overRate;
        $shiftearnings += $duration * $overRate;
      }
      //CASE 3: Already in daily overtime
      else if($daylimit > 0 && $dailyhourtotal > $daylimit
          && (($clockin >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz) || $include)){
        $totalOverHours += $duration;
        $totalOverDollars += $duration * $overRate;
        $shiftearnings += $duration * $overRate;
      }
      //CASE 4: Will exceed weekly overtime
      else if($weeklimit > 0 && ($weeklyhourtotal + $duration) > $weeklimit
          && (($clockin >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz) || $include)){
        $totalRegHours += ($weeklimit - $weeklyhourtotal);
        $totalRegDollars += ($weeklimit - $weeklyhourtotal) * $regRate;
        $totalOverHours += ($weeklyhourtotal + $duration) - $weeklimit;
        $totalOverDollars += (($weeklyhourtotal + $duration) - $weeklimit) * $overRate;
        $shiftearnings += ($weeklimit - $weeklytotalhours) * $regRate;
        $shiftearnings += (($weeklytotalhours + $duration) - $weeklimit) * $overRate;
      }
      //CASE 5: Will exceed daily overtime
      else if($daylimit > 0 && ($dailyhourtotal + $duration) > $daylimit
          && (($clockin >= $startz && $clockout <= $endz) || $include)){
        $totalRegHours += ($daylimit - $dailyhourtotal);
        $totalRegDollars += ($daylimit - $dailyhourtotal) * $regRate;
        $totalOverHours += ($dailyhourtotal + $duration) - $daylimit;
        $totalOverDollars += (($dailyhourtotal + $duration) - $daylimit) * $overRate;
        $shiftearnings += ($daylimit - $dailyhourtotal) * $regRate;
        $shiftearnings += (($dailyhourtotal + $duration) - $daylimit) * $overRate;
      }
      //CASE 6: No overtime
      else if(($clockin >= $start - $offset && $clockout <= $endz) || $include){
        $totalRegHours += $duration;
        $totalRegDollars += $duration * $regRate;
        $shiftearnings += $duration * $regRate;
      }
      //shift falls in supplied date range
      if($shift['ClockIn'] > $startz
          && $shift['ClockIn'] < $endz){
        $shift['ShiftEarnings'] = money_format('%!i', $shiftearnings); //add earnings to current punch
        array_push($shiftrecords, $shift);
      }
      $dailyhourtotal += $duration; //update daily total w/ shift length
      $weeklyhourtotal += $duration;    //update weekly total w/ shift length
      $totalEarnings += $shiftearnings; //record earnings in total
      $totalTime += $duration;  //record time in total
      $prevday = $currentday;
    }   //finished single shift

    //add total times/earnings to staff record
    foreach($staffquery as $staff){
      if($staff['StaffID'] == $staffID){
        $staff['TotalEarnings'] = money_format('%!i', $totalEarnings);
        $staff['TotalTime'] = $totalTime;
        array_push($newstaff, $staff);
        break;
      }
    }
    $totalEarnings = 0; //reset earnings for next employee
    $totalTime = 0; //reset time for next employee
  } //finished all of a single employee's shifts

$results = array(); //array for POST response
$results['RegularHours'] = $totalRegHours;
$results['RegularDollars'] = $totalRegDollars;
$results['OvertimeHours'] = $totalOverHours;
$results['OvertimeDollars'] = $totalOverDollars;
$results['TotalDollars'] = $totalRegDollars + $totalOverDollars;

$results['Staff'] = $newstaff; //key-val arrays w/ StaffID,TotalEarnings,TotalTime
$results['Shifts'] = $shiftrecords; //key-val arrays for shifts with earnings added

$salesquery = //DB query for total sales: Select sum(amount) From salesTbl Where: startz<=time<=endz
$totalSales = $salesquery[0];
$results['TotalSales'] = $totalSales;
if($totalSales == 0){ //no sales; labor is 100% of cost
  $results['LaborPercent'] = 100;
}else{
  $results['LaborPercent'] = (($totalRegDollars + $totalOverDollars) / $totalSales) * 100;
}
$this->response($results);
}
```

Feel free to use this; the results can easily be reported in an HTML table populated with an ng-repeat on the staff and shift arrays.

Comment: That's a big ass function. o,o

Comment: Yea sorry, didn't realize the size of the problem when I set out. I just tie this function to a submit button w/ the pickers

Comment: My first reaction is that you should be able to split that into smaller, more manageable functions.

Comment: Thank you. In the interest of hopefully flushing out some errors not related to function length, I'll work on adding an updated version to address that.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Classes**

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Using classes will not only make your code more readable, but also more easier to be maintainable and re-usable. It will help you separate the HTML logic and the PHP logic, instead of having a lot of messy PHP code in HTML files. My recommendation is, learn OOP Principals.

**Readability**

Variables like `$ONEWEEKSECONDS` and `$ONEDAYSECONDS` can be simplified as:

```
$ONEWEEKSECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
$ONEDAYSECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24;
```

This looks more read-able.

Also, looking at the length of your single function, I don't think anyone will bother even looking at it, they will simply give up. I suggest you to separate it into different smaller functions which perform **ONLY ONE TASK**.

**One function, one job**

When you look at your function, it is more like as if it is Hardcoded only for your task. A good programmer always code's it in a way, where it is re-usable. Have different functions for different tasks

Comment: *I don't think anyone will bother even looking at it, they will simply give up.* - That is not very nice to say, and I believe that you are totally wrong about that. It is a long function, yes, but that doesn't mean that everyone will give up when reading it.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg well, what I actually meant was, people will not really be getting a positive impression.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm familiar w/ common practices like classes, functions, and readability; I'm mainly concerned w/ having the payroll logic and arithmetic peer reviewed. Maybe I mistakenly figured this consolidated version of my live code would be more clear to a reader, without having to consult function definitions at each line.